# Found the cause of a metallic rattle/scrape from the rear - how urgent is this?

Tags: harley-davidson, drive-belt

Yesterday and today I noticed a strange scraping noise from the rear of my Ultra Limited, and was thinking grit in the brake, or possibly a bearing going as every time I looked there was nothing. Then when pushing back I heard a clunk and spotted this.

[image]

Looks like the rim that holds the drive belt on. My local Harley shop is 16 miles away - is this safe to ride there? Or is this a big no?

Considering I did 50 miles over the last two days on it and I don't think the noise had got worse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: ***It depends.***

The ring which came off is the guide for the belt. You can see the belt is ~1/2 way on the cog. It *might* stay there on the short trip to the dealership. It *might not*. That's your gamble. If it does come off, you run the risk of damaging the drive belt as well as locking up the back tire. A drive belt isn't very expensive in the grand scheme of things, however, bike riders should know if a tire locks up, you lose the gyro-stabilization of that tire, which means you lose control of the bike. I don't know about you, but I'm not fond of road rash (I'm assuming most people are not ... but there are a few people out there who might ... ;-).

Realistically, you need to put your bike on a trailer and take it to the shop. It's the safest/surest way of getting it there without issue.

Comment: A better Answer would be _don't ride it_. That loose belt guide is a recipe for the belt driving itself off the rear pulley. I've been riding motorcycles for 45 years, and I wouldn't ride around the block on a bike with that defect.

Comment: @David -It's always up to the owner as to what to do with their property. I just try to give the best advice I can.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps my perspective as a life-long rider, who's experienced motorcycle get-offs and spent >10 years teaching motorcycling in the California Motorcyclist Safety Program (administered by the CHP), makes my POV a bit more judgmental. I certainly did make it more personal. We do see that kind of judgment here, too, in the should-this-tire-be-replaced threads.

Comment: It's okay folks - I had already spoken to my mechanic, and the local garage is sending a truck to pick it up. Just figured I'd pop the question on here for others to see in future. I was actually very concerned when I saw the loose ring, as I had done nearly 50 miles at 70mph...